# How to rotate texture 90 degrees when using Object texture coordinate?

Tags: texture-coordinates

I feel so stupid as I can't figure out how to rotate a texture 90 degrees when using Object as the Texture Coordinate without it starting to stretch on the sides. I'm using Object instead of UV as I want the texture to be same size across multiple different sized objects.

[image]

The only way I could achieve it is by rotating the object itself 90 degrees or by rotating the textures in photoshop but both seem really hacky.

Any advice?

Comment: Hello :). There shouldn't be any stretching afaik. Perhaps the plank doesn't have its scale properly applied?

Comment: Did you try using a vector rotate node before the mapping node and setting the angle to 90?? Also, did you try box projection instead of trying to rotate the coordinates to get rid of the stretching??

Comment: Scale is applied correctly and texture is using box projection. It works great otherwise but I just cannot seem to rotate it. I tried vector rotate also but I ended up only with the same stretched result.

Comment: I found one more hack online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKmMW4ARyzM but I hope I do not need to use this as it seems like a lot of work to redo every object and arrays etc..

Comment: Can you share the blend file??

Answer (score 2):

For those who are also searching for a solution for rotating Object texture coördinates, I found a way by using the normal texture coördinates of the object. By attaching those to vector rotate node you can rotate just 1 single axis. I also added the possibility to rotate just a individual axis or rotate all axis with the same angle.
Maybe there is a more effective solution, but I'm still learning, so please let me know.

Here is the inside of the node group:
[image]

This is with the standard Object texture coördinates:

[image]

X axis set to 90 degrees:

[image]

every axis set to different angle:
[image]

I hope you you can appreciate my contribution.
Let me know if this a solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate around normal, you can do this like so:

[image]

To rotate just one axis, just choose a normal - doesn't have to be axis aligned.
To make it work for the opposite normal, in case of an axis aligned normal you can use "vector math: absolute".

[image]